# class using templated eigen matrix

Tags: c++, eigen3

I wrote a class like

```
class abc
{
public:
    template <typename Derived >
    abc( const Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matA,
         const Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matB,
         Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matC );
};

template <typename Derived >
abc::abc( const Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matA,
          const Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matB,
          Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matC )
{
    matC.derived().resize( matA.rows(), matA.cols() );

    for( int r = 0; r < matA.rows(); r++ )
    {
        for( int c = 0; c < matA.cols(); c++ )
        {
            matC(r,c) = log( matA(r,c) )/log( matB(r,c) );
        }
    }
}
```

but when using class abc in main
i get undefined reference error

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix< float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic > Matrix_Float;
main()
{
Matrix_Float matA, matB, matC;
// put values in matA, matB
    abc cls_abc( matA, matB, matC );
}
```

error is
error: undefined reference to `abc::abc < Eigen::Matrix < float, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > (Eigen::MatrixBase < Eigen::Matrix < float, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&, Eigen::MatrixBase < Eigen::Matrix < float, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&, Eigen::MatrixBase < Eigen::Matrix < float, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > &)'

is there anything wrong with syntax of class definition?

help please.

Comment: Is the definition of abc::abc right after the class definition as you showed in the incomplete code you posted?  Or is it elsewhere?

Comment: sorry. They are in separate files. abc.h and abc.cpp. main is separate. i compiled the code using qt-creator.

Comment: and if i use non templated version of constructor                                                                                            abc( const Matrix_Float &matA,
         const Matrix_Float &matB,
         Matrix_Float &matC ), it compiles just fine. so i think problem is in my definition of templated constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues. First, with template classes, you need to have the implementation available with the declaration (i.e. in the `.h` file, not the `.cpp`). Second, you want the class to be templated, note the constructor. Third, when using a templated class, you need to specify the template parameter.

Putting all that together, your class (`.h`) file should look like this:

```
template <typename Derived > class abc  // Template the class
{
public:
    //template <class Derived > // Don't put this here, but above
    abc(
        const Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matA,
        const Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matB,
        Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matC);
};

template <typename Derived >
abc<Derived>::abc(
    const Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matA,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matB,
    Eigen::MatrixBase < Derived > &matC)
{
    matC.derived().resize(matA.rows(), matA.cols());

    for (int r = 0; r < matA.rows(); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < matA.cols(); c++)
        {
            matC(r, c) = log(matA(r, c)) / log(matB(r, c));
        }
    }
}
```

and your `main()` should look like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) // just "main()" is so passé
{
    Matrix_Float matA, matB, matC;
    // put values in matA, matB
    abc<Matrix_Float> cls_abc(matA, matB, matC);
}
```